# Create editable excel spreadsheets

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7

Is there any python library that could write data from text file to excel. I also want the formulas to be reflected into the excel where I could edit the inputs in excel after writing it.

Comment: I think you can use open function of standard library to read the text file, and then try to use pandas to do what you want to do. Look at this, I don't know if it is what you would like to use.   https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.to_excel.html

Comment: Have a look at `openpyxl`:https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/